# Master-Detail: On row click in master (DataGrid), display details (DataGrid)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, master-detail

I'm not sure on how to implement this in Windows Presentation Foundation and Model View ViewModel architectural design pattern.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to populate the details (bottom datagrid) on every click on the master (top datagrid). The master is binded to an `ObservableCollection` and (supposed to be) so as the details. And also, if not too much, the changes in the details can be reflected back to the master, may it be on end edit of row in detail or end of cell edit or through a button click.

How do you think should this be accomplished? Any resource/sample that i can check?